# Do you get to draw a card if you rotate a tile?

Tags: untagged

In [Eruption](http://www.stratusgames.com/games/eruption), one gets to draw new tiles by connecting lava flows to cities. If there is already a tile connected to a city, and it is rotated using a Aftershock card, and the lava is still connected to the city in the same way, can one draw new cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, new draws can only be made if a new location is in contact with the lava.

Check the [rules](http://www.stratusgames.com/sites/default/files/eruption_instructions.pdf) on page 6: (emphasis mine)

> If this tile is rotated as shown, only one 
>   Action Card is drawn because there is 
>   *only one lava flow in contact with a new 
>   location* in the village

Also, this was [answered](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/694346/aftershock-question) on BoardgameGeek by the Designer Chris James

Comment: Good to know it is in the rules somewhere:-)